# Why is quantified propositional logic not part of first-order logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

If propositional logic is extended by quantifiers ($\forall$ and $\exists$) without adding functions and relations (or even objects and equality, i.e. we quantify over propositional-variables), the result could be called quantified propositional logic. This system is more expressive than propositional logic (the true quantified Boolean formulas are a PSPACE-complete language), but less expressive than first-order logic. Because first-order logic is sometimes considered as "the true logic", I find it interesting that it doesn't include this subsystem. (Second-order logic on the other hand includes it as a subsystem.)

**Note:** Even so this question is similar to another [question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6271/what-are-the-advantages-to-intentionally-omit-small-parts-from-first-order-logic) about omitting parts of first order logic, the motivation behind this question is different. It arose by considerations about the relation between constants and variables (and why there are "only" countably many different variables), and that there should be a similar relation between propositions and propositional-variables. (A related question would be "how many different variables/propositional-variables are required for deducing all consequences from a given set of axioms".)

Comment: What are you quantifying over?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Good point. I edited the question to clarify that I quantify over propositional-variables, and that the intended language doesn't even contain objects and equality.

Comment: In my opinion the best way to understand quantified propositional logic is to realize that this is exactly the true first-sentences (sometimes it is only the prenex ones) in a particular first-order structure, which is the two-elements Boolean algebra.

Comment: Sorry for the misprint "first-sentences". In my last comment I meant "first-order sentences".

Comment: @boumol Regarding the misprint, sometimes comments can still be edited, and if it's too late for this, I sometimes post a new comment with fixed typos, and then delete the original comment.

Comment: @boumol The proposed two-element Boolean algebra would have constant $0$ and $1$, and you would probably want to add the sentence $\lnot 0=1$. I guess I also need the sentence $(\forall x)[(x=0 \lor x=1)]$, and of cause the axioms for Boolean algebras. That interpretation indeed has nice properties, among other that the substitution laws for $\forall$ and $\exists$ are directly available without requiring any meta-theorems.

Comment: @Thomas: The two-element Boolean algebra means the set $\{0, 1\}$ endowed with the Boolean operations (negation, conjunction and disjunction are enough) and two constants 0,1 (one for each element). Notice that in this structure (indeed an algebra) the sentences $0 \neq 1$ and $\forall x ( x =0 \lor x=1)$ that you have just remarked are obviously true. My claim is simply the fact that the set $QBF$ (i.e., the true quantified Boolean formulas) coincides exactly with the first-order theory of the previous structure.

Comment: @boumol And because it coincides with the first-order theory, the question arises which axioms are necessary to describe that theory. After all, we are interested in the "true first-order sentences" in that theory (more than in the structure itself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This system of quantified propositional logic is straightforward to interpret into first-order logic. We make a theory $T$ that has a single, unary relation symbol, say $P$, and no other symbols in the signature, not even equality. Then, to quantify over "propositional variables", we quantify over elements in first order logic as usual. For each element $x$ in a model of $T$, $Px$ is either true or false, so the elements of the model can be treated as if they were propositional variables.

Thus the quantified propositional sentence $(\exists Q)(\forall R)[R \lor Q]$ is interpreted into $T$ as $(\exists q)(\forall r)[Pr \lor Pq]$.  In this way, every sentence of quantified propositional logic is interpreted as a sentence of $T$, and vice-versa.

If we wanted to add constant symbols to $T$, that would be equivalent to adding constant (i.e. non-variable) propositional variables to quantified propositional logic.

I would suggest that the main reason that we don't bother having quantified propositional variables in the "usual" framework for first-order logic is that they are not useful for formalizing the typical mathematical theories (group theory, linear orders, set theory, arithmetic, etc.), and a central goal in most presentations of first-order logic is to be able to formalize these theories.  The same holds for $\lambda$ terms to define functions. There is no reason that they could not be included in first-order theories, and in fact they sometimes are, but most presentations have no use for them.

Comment: The proposed interpretation must be augmented by the two sentences $(\exists x)[P x]$ and $(\exists x) [\lnot P x]$. I guess this should be enough to make it work. I wasn't aware of this when I asked the question. I agree that having quantified propositional variables would only complicate most presentations of first-order logic without adding any benefit. But still, trying to add it to first-order logic might be an interesting excercise, because it requires certain extensions (or modifications) of the model relation and the deduction system. It probably also leads to some meta-theorems.

Comment: @Mummert: I believe it is more convenient to think the truth value of $(\exists Q)(\forall R)[R \lor Q]$ as the truth value the first-order sentence $(\exists q)(\forall r)[ (r \lor q) = 1]$ in the two-elements Boolean algebra. It is not necessary to consider any extra predicate.

Comment: @boumol: in that case, instead of adding an extra predicate, you are adding extra function symbols such as $\lor$ to the signature. After all the $\lor$ in your formula is not the "or" of first-order logic that connects formulas; it is a function symbol from the signature of boolean algebras. So, yes, you can avoid adding the extra predicate symbol by adding function symbols instead.

Comment: I would rather say you can avoid the extra predicate by considering the adequate signature for Boolean algebras (for sure you have functional symbols for join, meet, negation, etc.). From the set perspective the $\lor$ is an extra functional symbol, but from the perspective of a Boolean algebra this function (the join) is already given.

Comment: I misread your formula at first, but I think we agree.

Comment: I had to read "The Seven Virtues of Simple Type Theory" and then do some serious thinking before I could figure out the "The same holds for λ terms to define functions. There is no reason that they could not be included in first-order theories, and in fact they sometimes are, ..." part. It actually seems to be a nice system/language. I decided that the first-order restriction would mean that λ can only bind to normal variables or propositional-variables. Then (it seems) I only have to add an "if X then a else b" construct to get a nice expressive language.